# Richtung Atlantik oder mit "in" Richtung Atlantik?

Tags: usage

"Im Sommer 2004 tobte der Hurrikan Charley aus dem Golf von Mexiko über Florida hinweg Richtung Atlantik."

"Richtung Atlantik" <- kann dieser Satz so stehen ohne Praepositionen zu nutzen?

vielen Dank im Voraus!

Comment: Willkommen bei German.SE. Geht es nur um ein "ja/neiN" oder auch um Unterschiede in der Benutzung?

Answer (score 6):

Ja, es ist beides möglich, sowohl mit "in" als auch ohne.

Note you would typically specify directions with zero article. E.g. we would say "Der Fluss mündet in den Atlantik", but "Es bewegt sich Richtung Atlantik".

Answer (score 1):

**(In) Richtung XYZ** ist ein feststehender Ausdruck, der den Ausdruck *nach XYZ* ergänzt. Der Unterschied ist subtil. Das *in* ist fakultativ.

> Der Sturm zieht nach Nordost.
>
> Der Sturm zieht (in) Richtung Nordost.

Diese beiden Sätze bedeuten das gleiche, da *Nordost* ohnehin schon eine Richtung darstellt. Mit echten Zielen gibt es hingegen einen Unterschied:

> Ich fahre nach Nashville. Wegen der Country-Musik.

Nashville ist mein Ziel.

> Ich fahre also (in) Richtung Memphis. Richtung Elvis. Steigen Sie einfach ein.

Von New York aus? Das stimmt sicher. Und der arme Elvis-Fan muss sich jetzt die Ohren zustopfen.